# .pop is cutting off after prematurely

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a Pig Latin translator but if you type in more then two words for an input the .pop function starts to go nuts and I cant figure out why. Information and a fix would be helpful. Thanks.

```
x = input("Type phrase or word you would like to be translated to pig latin:")
x = x.strip()
y = x.split()
z = []
n = len(y) -1
a = 0

for i in range(0, n):
    first_word = y.pop(a)
    pig_latin = first_word[1:len(first_word)] + first_word[0] + "ay"
    a += 1
    z.append(pig_latin)

print(pig_latin)
```

Comment: *.pop function starts to go nuts* - what does that mean exactly? If you want to always take the first word, use `.pop(0)`. You are advancing `a` but `pop` actually **deletes** elements from the list, so you skip every second word

Comment: Sorry, I mean that I was getting pop index out of range but this makes it clear. I forgot  that it takes away from the original list. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems. First, you keep reducing the size of the list with `pop(a)` but also increment `a`. `a` eventually exceeds the size of the now-diminished list and you get the error. As a first cut, we can fix the bugs in the original

```
x = input("Type phrase or word you would like to be translated to pig latin:")
x = x.strip()
y = x.split()
z = []
#n = len(y) -1
n = len(y)
#a = 0

for i in range(0, n):
    first_word = y.pop(0)
    pig_latin = first_word[1:len(first_word)] + first_word[0] + "ay"
    #a += 1
    z.append(pig_latin)

#print(pig_latin)
print(" ".join(z))
```

But there is no advantage to doing the error prone indexing. We could shorten the program to

```
x = input("Type phrase or word you would like to be translated to pig latin:")
y = x.strip().split()
z = []

for word in y:
    pig_latin = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"
    z.append(pig_latin)

print(" ".join(z))
```

Or use list comprehensions to reduce it further still

```
x = input("Type phrase or word you would like to be translated to pig latin:")
z = [word[1:] + word[0] + "ay" for word in x.strip().split()]
print(" ".join(z))
```